# Newtons Second Law: did i disprove it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Lets take a box and keep it touching to a wall. The mass is m and let's say I apply a force in the direction of the wall intenting to move the box through it(Which is not possible!). I apply a force of 5N. and as I can't move the box acceleration is 0.

Mass = m
Force = 5N
Acceleration = 0 m/s

Hence F = ma
=> 5 = m × 0
=> m = 5/0 = infinity

So is the mass of the object infinity
How do we explain this?

Comment: Do you really think it's plausible that you disproved Newton's second law?

Comment: When you attempt to calculate acceleration using Newton's second law you are implicitly promising to account for all forces, not just those you are paying attention to.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. If you encounter problems like this, the community usually is much more helpful if you ask "Where did I go wrong?" or "What did I miss?" instead of "Did I disprove this centuries old physics theorem?".

Answer (score 6):

The wall exerts a force on the block which balances the force you are applying, so the *net* force is zero.

Answer (score 4):

Not you have not disproved the 2nd Law. You have only considered one force. There are basically 4 forces acting on the box: the 5N force that you exert, the force that the wall exerts on the box, the force that the Earth pulls on the box, and the normal force (the ground acting on the box). The F in Newton's second law refers to the resultant force, not just one of the forces.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law relates the **net** force on a body, that is the summation of all forces acting on the body, with the acceleration of the body.

A book resting on a table is another example where the body is not accelerating, yet there is a force acting on it (gravity). But in both cases, there are also reaction forces (Newton's 3rd law) present to cause the net force to be zero.